# newenvironment with options or named parameters/arguments

Tags: macros, environments

How can i define a `\newenvironment` with named parameters/argument/option
like the following dummy code:

```latex
\DeclareOption{language}[1]{This is #1}

\newenvironment[language]{hello}{
     #language
}{}
```

Designated Usage:

```latex
\begin[language=German]{hello}
    SomeText
\eng{hello}
```

Resolves to:

> This is German
> SomeText

The reason i want this is to have a named option at the top level when using the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareKeys[flymg]{language .code:n={This is #1}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{hello}
  {O{language=hello}}
  {\SetKeys[flymg]{#1}}
  {}

\begin{document}
\begin{hello}
some text
\end{hello}

\begin{hello}[language=german]
mehr Text
\end{hello}
\end{document}
```

[image]